# DPA 4060/61 alternative

Tags: recording, microphone

I’m looking at buying a pair of 4060s or 4061s, though was just shocked to realise that to get them as XLR OPs Id need to spend another £160 for connectors!!!! Heading beyond my budget now.

Can anyone suggest an alternative, cheaper pair of lav omnis that do a (near) equally good job??

Im looking for them primarily as a discreet way of doing stereo field recording about the UK, as I’m sick of lugging around shotguns. 
Thanks

Comment: haven't checked but are the Sennheiser MKE2 ..s more expensive?

Answer (score 1):

I can vouch for using the Sony ECM 77 lav mics. Very small capsules (although not quite as small as DPA) and give very true and sensitive pickup of surrounding sounds. :)
http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/product/broad-pro-audio-wired-lapel/ecm-77bc/overview/
What is also good about these mics are the simple mounting clips and pop shields

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will have a suggestion for a pair of cheaper lavs, but I'm not certain how this busts your budget. At ~$430 USD for a single 4060 (adapter required) and ~$900 USD for a [4060SMK](http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=item&category=130&item=24083) kit (microdot>XLR adapters and a host of useful mounts included), I'd think that's your answer.

I dug down and saved up for the [4060SMK](http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=item&category=130&item=24083) set myself and found it's well worth the price of admission. Never once regretted it's purchase.

Comment: Agree Steve, and I did dig and bought 2 4061s second hand. So a minor compromise in not getting new 4060s but better than getting cheaper mics I think

Answer (score 0):

Check out the RODE Lavs. They have a great modular system where you just unscrew the connector and replace it with a different one, XLR, mini XLR, jack etc. You can also just replace the cable, and they do long thin cables as well.

As for the mics themselves, I've done shoots where I used the DPA's along side the RODE's and they were incredibly close in their sound. Unless you are going to be recording in very very quiet places they will be a good option. The ruggedness and being able to replace the cables is a bonus in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of some DIY...
http://www.frogloggers.com/BT%20EM172.htm
These primo electrets are as far as I know the same capsules used in the sony M10 handheld recorder.
They are pretty quiet, way lower noise floor than the DPAs, but they don't have the same pleasing sound. The M10 has generally been considered the lowest noise floor recorder using built in mics there is.
And for 10USD a piece, you really can't go wrong.
I made several stealth rigs and a few other stereo recording setups with these mics. Works fine as long as you know how to solder and work within their limits.
To work with louder spl they need a higher voltage than regular pip power though.
Not hard to build, but as I said a little bit of DIY.

Comment: wow, wow, thank you so much for this! the sensitivity is amazing (39mV/Pa). indeed not the DPA sound but not the DPA price either ;

Comment: I've used the ten units I bought a lot. Sold a pair to a friend. Accidentally sunk a pair in water, no they didn't survive, but at 10 USD a piece I was just sad that I had to re solder. Built a DIY SASS stereo setup. Mounted stealth units on my closed back headphones. Only have one spare pair left. Need to buy more.

Comment: Yep, Em172's are cool and low noise, but they don't like too much low end. They crap out, even without driving your meters into the red.

Comment: As I said, they need more power not just regular pip power.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a pair of the Naiant X-X which came recommended by Jez Riley French as a budget option to the 4060s (he did also recommend the Rode Lavs) and they're performing incredibly well for a $100 for a pair.

I've used them as ambient mics while recording Kodo Drummers and they delivered beautifully smooth low end, and as a stereo pair for nature recording where self-noise wise they are good also. I'll post some samples next week when I'm back in the studio.